# What would be the downsides of storing many-to-many relates in a JSON field instead of in a tertiary table?

Tags: sql, orm, many-to-many, relational-database

Say I intend to have the following objects stored in a relational database (pseudo-code):

```
Domain:
   id: 123
   Name: A
   Variables: Thing_X, Thing_Y, Thing_Z

Domain:
   id: 789
   Name: B
   Variables: Thing_W, Thing_X, Thing_Y
```

I know the standard way to structure the many-to-many relationship between Domains and Variables would be to use a tertiary table. However, I think I can do some *interesting stuff,* if I represent the relates in a JSON. And, would like to know the deficiencies of doing something like the following:

```
Domain:
   id: 123
   name: A
   variable_relates_JSON:{
      {table: 'Variable', id: 314, name: 'Thing_X'},
      ...
   }

 Variable:
   id: 314
   name: Thing_X
   domain_relates_JSON:{
      {table: 'Domain', id: 123, name: 'A'},
      ...
   }
```

I've made another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388658/what-is-the-lookup-time-through-a-tertiary-table-in-a-relational-database-sqlit) more specifically about the time complexity of this JSON method versus using a tertiary table. I'm happy to hear answers to that question here as well. But, I'm also interested in general challenges I may encounter with this approach.

Comment: Performance and space are the two major downsides.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the response! Would you be able to elaborate? I don't know enough about how lookups through a tertiary table are actually performed to compare time complexities that would affect performance, and I know little to nothing about relational database CPU performance. Additionally, would a JSON field really take up more space than a-whole-nother table?

Answer (score 0):

JSON strings incur the overhead of having to store the *name* of the field as well as the value.  This multiplies the size of the data.

In addition, dates and numbers are stored as strings.  In a regular database format, 2020-01-01 occupies 4 bytes or so versus the 10 bytes in a string (not including the delimiters).  Similarly for numbers.

More space required for the data slows down databases.  Then, searching for a particular JSON requires scanning or parsing the JSON string.  Some databases provide support for binary JSON formats or strings to facilitate this, but you have to set that up as part of the table.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, Gordon! One follow-up question: if I only ever need to query for an index, will the added size significantly affect my query time?

Comment: @LiamMonninger . . . I don't know what you mean "query for an index".

Comment: The only fields I need to query over are indices--primary keys and unique fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an issue I thought of: **CONCURRENT UPDATES**.

Continuing the example above, let's say users assign both Variable `Thing_XX` and Variable `Thing_YY` to Domain `A`.

For each assignment, I will have to get the JSON and add the relevant id somewhere in its structure. If either gets the JSON before the other finishes assignment, then it will overwrite the assignment of the other.

A scrappy solution might be to somehow 'lock' the field while someone is editing it. But, that could become quite problematic.